# SciPy minimization of two-dimentional function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to minimize my two-dimentional function:

```
def error(w0, w1):
    sum = 0
    for index, row in data.head(5).iterrows():
        sum += (row['Height'] - (w0 + w1*row['Weight']))**2
    return sum
```

with `scipy optimize` package, using `minimize` function.

I set my initial variables:

```
w0 = 0
w1 = 0
```

And had described the boundaries:

```
bnds = ((-100, 100), (-5, 5))
```

But, when I try to minimize my function

```
res = opt.minimize(error,w0,w1,method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bnds)
```

I receive an error:

```
ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds
```

How should I minimize properly?

Answer (score 1):

Your call to minimize is wrong:

```
res = opt.minimize(error, [w0, w1], method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bnds)
```

`x0` needs to be some array. The way you did it, your second dimension of the initial-point is being interpreted as some other argument in this function's [signature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) (meaning: only w0 is interpreted as x0, which is a scalar and not a array of size 2 -> incompatible with those bounds).

The same principle applies to your function:

```
def error(x):
    w0, w1 = x
    sum = 0
    for index, row in data.head(5).iterrows():
        sum += (row['Height'] - (w0 + w1*row['Weight']))**2
    return sum
```

Comment: well, as I try the way, you have mentioned I will receive an error: error() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Because your funtion needs the same modification. See **edit**.